# finding HTTPS images with BeautifulSoup, python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm iterating through all the `img`'s in a `request.POST` to see if they are HTTPS (I'm using [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start) to help)

Here's my code:

```
content = request.POST['content']
print(content) #prints:
<p>test test test</p><br><p><img src="https://www.treefrogfarm.com/store/images/source/IFE_A-K/ClarySage2.jpg" alt=""></p><br><p>2nd 2nd</p><br><p><img src="https://www.treefrogfarm.com/store/images/source/IFE_A-K/ClarySage2.jpg" alt=""></p>

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
for image in soup.find_all('img'):
    print('Source:', image.get('src')[:8]) #prints Source: https://
    if image.get('src')[:7] == "https://":
        print('HTTPS')
    else:
        print('Not HTTPS')
```

Even though `image.get('src')[:7] == "https://"`, the code still prints `Not HTTPS`.

Any idea why?

Comment: `'https:/' != 'https://'`

Comment: Have a look at [**`urllib.parse`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html)

Comment: You specified a 7-character slice and compared it to an 8-character string.  These can never be equal.

Comment: In general, this is exactly why Python strings have the `startswith` method, so you don't make silly off-by-one errors like this. (But in this case, you probably should be using a URL parser, as @PeterWood suggests.)

Answer (score 3):

Well for starters, `'https://'` is 8 characters, so there's no way that a slice of 7 characters can match it.

Also, please make your question titles actually indicative of the problem you're having rather than unrelated accusations about the python operators.

Answer (score 0):

to match the `https://` string the appropriate slice would be `:8` instead of `:7`

`if image.get('src')[:8] == "https://":`